# Why is X not a legitimate Moore family?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, lattice-orders

According to the definitions in the appendix A.1 of *Principles of Program Analysis*,

$L = (\mathcal{P}(S), \subseteq)$ for $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$ is a complete lattice.

Furthermore, neither $X = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\} \subseteq \mathcal{P(S)}$ or $Y = \{\{1\}, \{2\}\} \subseteq \mathcal{P(S)}$ are considered Moore families of $L$.

I can understand why the set $Y = \{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$ is not a Moore family.

For example, given that $Y' = \emptyset \subseteq Y$ holds (since this true for every set), then my understanding is the following must also hold:

$$\bigcap{Y'} \in Y$$

And thus the greatest lower bound for $Y'$ would be in $Y$ (as must be the case for all possible $Y' \subseteq Y$).

However, $\bigcap{Y'} = \bigcap{\emptyset} = \emptyset \notin Y$ and so we have our counter example for $Y$, and hence $Y$ is not closed under greatest lower bounds.

For, $X$, though, I'm having trouble finding a counter example. Since $\emptyset \in X$ is true, I can't see how any possible intersection of the sets in $X$ would yield a result that is in turn not in $X$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not my field, so I'm not answering, but a quick google search suggested that Moore families must be closed under intersection **and** contain the set $S$. $X$ does not contain $S$. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @user803264: thanks. I think that's the one. Would mind referencing the page you found this at? I did some googling around before and must have missed this one.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309611139_Recursive_definition_of_the_lattice_of_Moore_families

Comment: I don't know what is a Moore family, but, picking on user803264's comment, if it is closed under intersection of all subsets, then it contains $S$; indeed, contrary to your claim, $\bigcap\varnothing$ is $S$, in this case. Generally, if $L$ is a complete lattice with top element $1$ and bottom $0$,  then $\bigwedge\varnothing = \bigvee L = 1$ and $\bigwedge L = \bigvee\varnothing = 0$.